# Unsplitting/merging lines that have coincident endpoints using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, grouping, st-intersects, st-union

I have a large dataset of lines/linestrings (ie. a road network), which is unregularly segmentised/ split and the lines needs to be merged at coincident endpoints (if *only* two lines are touching). I'd like to achieve this with PostGIS.

The image below shows the current network data (1), the current result if start and end nodes are extracted (2), and the desired output (3). The points are only for the purpose of visualising start and end points of lines.

[image]

I am aware of eg. the `Unsplit Line (Data Management)` function in ArcGIS Pro ([see here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/unsplit-line.htm)), which can achieve the desired output. I am trying to replicate this functionality.

I am also aware of the `ST_Union` and `ST_UnaryUnion` function which can union/ unsplit two input geometries (both are aggregate function so they can be used with a `GROUP BY` SQL command), as well as the `ST_Touches` and `ST_Intersects`function which can evaluate whether two geometries intersect in PostGIS.

How can I efficiently group those lines together which touch at their end points, using intersections of more than 2 lines as group separations?

Here are some trials:

Merge lines based on a group id (nb I don't know how this group id could be generated):

```
SELECT max(id) as id, ST_LineMerge(ST_Union(geom)) as geom
FROM line_data
GROUP BY id;
```

I would need to check if lines are touching at their start and end points, here is an example on how to get those points:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (ST_DumpPoints(ST_Union(ST_StartPoint(a.geom),ST_EndPoint(a.geom)))).geom
FROM line_data as a;
```

Here is a GeoJSON with some example data (using a UK projection):

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "line_data",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::27700" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 1 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiLineString", "coordinates": [ [ [ 404105.557298680825625, 441484.677229618187994 ], [ 404091.557298680825625, 441490.677229618187994 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 2 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiLineString", "coordinates": [ [ [ 404091.557298680825625, 441490.677229618187994 ], [ 404088.934298680804204, 441491.851229618187062 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 3 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiLineString", "coordinates": [ [ [ 404088.934298680804204, 441491.851229618187062 ], [ 404087.530958589049987, 441492.488016092858743 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 4 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiLineString", "coordinates": [ [ [ 404085.202298680844251, 441493.522229618160054 ], [ 404069.072298680839594, 441500.744896284828428 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 5 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiLineString", "coordinates": [ [ [ 404092.23729868081864, 441499.302229618187994 ], [ 404091.817298680834938, 441498.327229618211277 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 6 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiLineString", "coordinates": [ [ [ 404091.817298680834938, 441498.327229618211277 ], [ 404091.436298680840991, 441497.438229618186597 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 7 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiLineString", "coordinates": [ [ [ 404082.918298680800945, 441488.421229618194047 ], [ 404085.202298680844251, 441493.522229618160054 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 8 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiLineString", "coordinates": [ [ [ 404091.436298680840991, 441497.438229618186597 ], [ 404088.934298680804204, 441491.851229618187062 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 9 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiLineString", "coordinates": [ [ [ 404079.932298680825625, 441481.647229618160054 ], [ 404081.162298680806998, 441484.392229618213605 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 10 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiLineString", "coordinates": [ [ [ 404081.162298680806998, 441484.392229618213605 ], [ 404082.067298680834938, 441486.467229618167039 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 11 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiLineString", "coordinates": [ [ [ 404082.067298680834938, 441486.467229618167039 ], [ 404082.918298680800945, 441488.421229618194047 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 12 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiLineString", "coordinates": [ [ [ 404087.530958589049987, 441492.488016092858743 ], [ 404087.521519799542148, 441492.492299084202386 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 13 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiLineString", "coordinates": [ [ [ 404087.521519799542148, 441492.492299084202386 ], [ 404086.918862026010174, 441492.765764027833939 ], [ 404086.1045236493228, 441493.116771948814858 ], [ 404085.705842245894019, 441493.295938385475893 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 14 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiLineString", "coordinates": [ [ [ 404085.705842245894019, 441493.295938385475893 ], [ 404085.202298680844251, 441493.522229618160054 ] ] ] } }
]
}
```

---

The following code solves the issue only partly, but introduces additional problems.
We first union all linestrings into one big multilinestring via `ST_Union`, this single multilinestring is then fed into `ST_LineMerge` which joins lines according to:

> Lines are joined at their endpoints at 2-way intersections. Lines are
> not joined across intersections of 3-way or greater degree.

With the `(ST_Dump()).geom` we can then extract the individually merged linesstrings out from the single multilinestring.

```
SELECT max(a.id), (ST_Dump(ST_LineMerge(ST_Union(a.geom)))).geom as geom
FROM lines_data AS a;
```

*However, this process splits also lines that do not share a common node, ie. are simply crossing, but with no coincidental points. This is quite problematic for the type of network. We also lose the individual line ids–though this is a minor problem.*

Comment: I am wondering if the easiest way to do this would be creating a topology and route over it from all nodes to all other nodes with degree 3. Afterwards route from the dead ends with degree one to the next degree 3 node. I think this way you would find the groups of "edges" given your objective. If you think this could work, I would give it a shot for you.

Comment: Hi Timothy, thanks for your reply and suggestion. I am not sure exactly how this would look like, but I am using pg_routing and the line_data is a routable network topology–so I would definitely be interested in a solution utilising topology here!

Comment: I started this but with the genius response from @geozelot below, I will stop at once :-) really nice approach!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The graph-theoretical answer for simplifying edge topologies and decreasing the size of a graph would be [*contraction*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_contraction) - implemented as [stable function](https://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/pgr_contraction.html) as of *pgRouting* 3.0.

To perform a *linear graph contraction* on your topology, run

```
SELECT *
FROM   pgr_contraction(
         $$
           SELECT <edge_id>, <source>, <target>, <cost>, <reverse_cost>
           FROM   <edge_table>
         $$,
         ARRAY[2],
         directed => <true/false>
       )
;
```

The returned set of rows will hold information on what vertices have been removed from the primary topology, and the full topology information of the contracted edges.

#### SOLUTION, ADDED BY OP:

Given that the example data has been prepared as pg_routing topology (incl. `source` & `target` columns), a grouping `gid` and subsequent line merge can be achieved as follows:

The `contracted_vertices` column in the resulting `pg_contraction` table can subsequently be unnested and joined to the lines_data table based on matches in the `source`and `target` columns respectively. Using this newly named `gid` column as `GROUP BY` lines geometries can be merged via `ST_Union`. The `GROUP BY gid, CASE WHEN gid IS NULL THEN id ELSE 0 END` line groups by ´gid´ only if gid is not null, otherwise the id column is used as grouping to generate a row for each line segment that has no contracted vertex.

```
SELECT max(a.id) as id, ST_Union(a.geom) as geom
FROM ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT a.*, b.id as gid
    FROM lines AS a
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        id, unnest(contracted_vertices) AS vertex
    FROM   (SELECT id, contracted_vertices 
            FROM   pgr_contraction(
                $$
                  SELECT id, source, target, ST_Length(geom) as cost, ST_Length(geom) as reverse_cost
                  FROM lines
                $$,
                ARRAY[2],
                 directed => false
            )) as contraction_table
    ) AS b ON a.source = b.vertex OR a.target = b.vertex
) as a
GROUP BY gid,
CASE WHEN gid IS NULL THEN id ELSE 0 END;
```

Comment: Hi geozelot, many thanks for pointing me to the `pgr_contraction`, this looks exactly like the function I was looking for! I will try to convert the resulting 'contracted_vertices' column to an edge grouping, add the solution to my question, and accept your comment as solution once I have done this. Just as a note, i) I think you need to add `<id>` to the pgr_contraction SELECT command (at least it throws an error if this is missing), and ii) it does not seem to alter the `<edge_table>` in place, but rather `RETURNS SETOF (type, id, contracted_vertices, source, target, cost)`.

Comment: @krenz gotcha, I haven't tried it recently. I updated my answer for now, feel free to either add the full solution *as an answer* (you can self-accept), or add it to mine if you feel generous.